# Should questions about drinking games be considered as on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

**Should questions about drinking games be considered as on topic?**

I personally do not care which way the answers go. I simple would like to know if we could consider if drinking games would be considered on topic here.

It might or might not bring in more traffic to the site. Thus I like to see if any input from those who use this site can be heard on this subject matter.

[**List of drinking games**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_drinking_games)

Happy to see anyone weighing in on this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it may possibly be on topic. Will have to phrase the question(s) accordingly to remain on topic and thus opening a new subject matter.